# How to cancel an ongoing touch-drag (scroll) event?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

How to cancel an ongoing (after it has started) touch and drag (ie. scroll) on mobile (specifically, iOS Safari)?

I have tried:

```
window.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    if (disableScrolling) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

That does not work.

The only solution that did work is:

```
window.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    if (disableScrolling) {
        window.scrollTo(0, lastKnownScrollTopBeforeDisablingScrolling);
    }
});
```

However, it produces a glitchy experience.

`disableScrolling` variable is set true at the time while user is scrolling (in response to entering a specific area on the page).